# gsutil bashrc file path setting

Tags: command-line, bashrc, paths

Actually I have just installed **gsutil** by following the instructions [**here**](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install).

But now when I am typing `gsutil` at command prompt I am getting following:

```
No command was given.
Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something. 
Try `/usr/bin/gsutil --help' for more information.
```

What can be my mistake or am I supposed to do something else?

Is it due to that I have not set correct path in my `.bashrc file`? Following path is set by me in `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$usr/bin/gsutil
```

and firstly I had set it to:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/vishal/Downloads/gsutil/gsutil
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989741/how-to-configure-gsutil, the "No command was given" message is returned by the program `gsutil` in the Ubuntu package `gsutil`. That is *not* the Google Cloud Storage utility, but an older program to "configure and manage GrandStream BudgeTone 100 VOIP and GS2000 phones." This is mentioned in a prominent "Warning" in a red box on the Google help page that you link to.

Although you could probably fix this problem by configuring your `PATH` correctly (so that the Google `gsutil` is found before the `gsutil` from the Ubuntu package), if you don't have a "BudgeTone" phone, you can also simply uninstall the Ubuntu package `gsutil`.

Answer (score 1):

The program `gsutil` needs some more arguments to run. So `gsutil` alone will not produce anything helpfuk, except the output you pasted.  So i.e. to upload your PNG photos issue the command

```
gsutil cp *.png gs://my_pngs
```

Just have a look at the [gsutil Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_reference_guide). This document explains how you should use `gsutil`.

But also your definition of the `$PATH` seems not correct. You wrote:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$usr/bin/gsutil
```

Have you really set a variable `$usr`? I assume you want to use the directory `/usr`. If this is your intention you should substitute the `$` and write a `/` instead. The second questions that comes into mind is: Is `/usr/bin/gsutil` a directory? I assume this is your executable file. So your definition will not work anyway. If you try to enter `echo $PATH` you will see that `/usr/bin` is already defined as part of your path. So `gsutil` will be called like any other program and there is no need setting the `PATH` variable.

Comment: This path has been set by me in .bashrc file
export PATH=${PATH}:/HOME/vishal/Downloads/gsutil/gsutil

and when i do echo $PATH,this gets displayed

/HOME/vishal/Downloads/gsutil/gsutil

but still when i do gsutil config or gsutil mb gs://<anybucketName>(say gsutil mb gs://Project)
it displays

No command was given.

Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something. 
Try `/usr/bin/gsutil --help' for more informatio

Comment: What happens when you enter: `~/Downloads/gsutil/gsutil config`? What is the output of `which gsutil`?

Comment: hi qbi the following message i getNo command was given.

Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something.
Try `/usr/bin/gsutil --help' for more information

Comment: Have you entered the command exactly like I wrote it down? What is the output of the second command (`which gsutil`)?

Comment: hi qbi,   Acually gsutil is in my /Downlaods/gsutil/gsutil folder  Now when i go to /download/gsutil and enter the command gsutil config(as prescribed in gsutil document  https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install)         i got following output                      No command was given.

Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something.
Try `/usr/bin/gsutil --help' for more information.

Comment: I understand what you did. But to find out more about an eventual error it would be nice to do exactly what I wrote. This would help me to get an idea what goes wrong.

Comment: Basically i think the Gsutil which has been given on https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install
is actually the 
 The Grandstream BudgeTone 100 VOIP and GX2000 telephones 
 and these are telephones that does VOIP, from a company called Grandstream.So that is why the follwoing output is comming

vishal@XXXX:~$ gsutil cp *.png gs://my_pngs
No command was given.

Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something.
Try `/usr/bin/gsutil --help' for more information.

But then from where to get thae GSutil which is command line tool for interaction with google cloud storage

Answer (score 1):

Rather than downloading and installing from the internet I strongly recommend to use the built-in package management in Ubuntu.

This makes sure that applications are tested to run on your distribution version, and it also ensures that applications are installed in the appropriate place in the file system. It also lets you easily remove an application in case you don't need it anymore.

To do so search for an application in the Ubuntu Software Center.

You can install gsutil on your system via an apt command with `sudo apt install gsutil` in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Only rarely you may have to add a [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) as a software source from which you know you can install an application that is not available otherwise.

Only as a last resort you can also install an application from its source code or from an installation program that may be offered (e.g. in case of closed source software). Such software may not be tested to run without issues.

Comment: what about those of us using WSL?